Remote Desktop certificate error, but certificate is OK
I have a computer running at home, that I sometimes connect to over a VPN using RDP. At first I was getting certificate errors, because the computer was using a self-signed certificate. Since I have a simple CA that I use for HTTPS with local hostnames, I used it to generate a certificate for RDP as well.
I set the computer to use that certificate and the CA is trusted on my other devices.
However, when connecting, I still get a warning saying the certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority.
Clicking view certificate and checking the certification path however, shows "This certificate is OK".
How can I stop the warning without clicking "Don't ask me again"?



The second screenshot is from the “view certificate” from the first? Which certificate store did you install the Root CA in and which store did you install the user certificate in?

Yes the second screenshot is the window that opens when I click "View certificate". The certificate is installed in "Certificates - Local Computer > Personal" and RDP was set to use it. On my "client" PC I have the Root CA in "Certificates - Current User > Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
